# Invalid webhook response (302 Found) from Telegram bot in PHP (MVC)

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Good day! I have an MVC site in PHP. The essence of the problem is that when receiving a webhook response, Telegram sends an error message - **Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found**.

- The webhook was successfully registered using the link https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setwebhook?url=https://mysite-domain/webhook.
- SSL: certificate Let's Encrypt.

*Result of getWebhookInfo() method*

```
    [ok] => 1
    [result] => Array
          (
                    [url] => https://mysite-domain/webhook
                    [has_custom_certificate] => 
                    [pending_update_count] => 8
                    [last_error_date] => 1658579570
                    [last_error_message] => Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found
                    [max_connections] => 40
                    [ip_address] => x.x.x.x
          )
```

I think the problem is in .htaccess.
The root folder has .htaccess (1) and requests are redirected to the /public folder. And in .htaccess(2), requests are sent to index.php. Learning. Thanks in advance to all those who help in solving this problem.

*Folder structure:*

```
 - app
 - ---controllers
 - ---models
 - ---views 
 - config
 - public
 - ---files
 - ---css, js
 - ---index.php
 - ---.htaccess (2)
 - vendor
 - composer.json
 - .htaccess (1)
```

*.htaccess (1):*

```
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

*.htaccess (2):*

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

    php_flag session.use_trans_sid Off
    php_flag session.use_only_cookie On
    php_flag session.auto_start On

    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 604800

    Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Both those .htaccess appear to perform only internal rewrites, not external redirects - so it doesn't look like those were actually responsible.